# symfony Template's name in render()

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create login page, and i want just to test Doctrine if i'ts working or not but i faced this probleme with template's Location so this is my code

```
    namespace Login\loginBundle\Controller;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
       public function loginAction()
{
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository=$em->getRepository('Login\loginBundle\Entity\Login\Utilisateur');

    $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password));

    if($user){
        return $this->render('Login\loginBundle\Resources\views\Default\index.html.twig',array('name'=>$user->getNom()));
    }
    else{
        return $this->render('Login\loginBundle\Resources\views\Default\index.html.twig',array('name'=>'login failed'));
    }

}
```

This is the Location of my template
Login\loginBundle\Resources\views\Default\index.html.twig

and this is the error i got :

```
    Unable to find template "Login\loginBundle:Default:index.html.twig".
    500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
    3 linked Exceptions:
    Twig_Error_Loader »
    InvalidArgumentException »
    InvalidArgumentException »

    [4/4] InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template                   "Login\loginBundle:Default:index.html.twig".   +

    [3/4] Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "Login\loginBundle:Default:index.html.twig".   +

     [2/4] InvalidArgumentException: Template name "Login/loginBundle:Default:index.html.twig" is not valid.   +

     [1/4] InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "Login/loginBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?   +
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle

```
$this->render('LoginloginBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
```

Comment: thank you it works but i should put  loginBundle instead of LoginloginBundle because i change it's name

Answer (score 0):

[Render your template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) like:

```
// {# yourBundle/Resources/views/someFolder/index.html.twig #}
return $this->render(
     'someFolder/index.html.twig',
      array('variable' => $something)
);
```

Comment: this is work but it's not leading me to the page i want i tooks me some other page

Comment: probably you're redirection to the `app/` resources, can you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

The naming of your template string is not correct.
In your case it should be as follows:

```
$this->render('@Login/loginBundle/Default/index.html.twig');
```

I'd suggest you use an IDE like PHPStorm with the Symfony2 plugin to make use of the intellisense.